# RSpec stubbing only works for first request, does not work for subsequent requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I am writing request specs for my app and I am having an issue with stubbing for multiple requests.

My test:

```
it "adding a text response element to the campaign" do
  TextResponsesController.any_instance.stub(:current_user).and_return(@user)

  get new_campaign_text_response_path(@campaign)
  expect(response).to render_template(:new)

  post "/campaigns/#{@campaign.id}/text_responses", { :text_response => {:name => "test", :campaign_id => @campaign.id, :keyword => @campaign.keyword, :message => "testing", :clip_id => Content::DEFAULT[1], :sender_name => "tester", :start_date => Time.now, :end_date => Time.now + 86400} }
  expect(@campaign.components.first.class).to equal TextResponse
end
```

In this example, I am stubbing the :current_user method on any instance of the  controller so it can emulate a logged in user, otherwise it would just redirect to the sign in page.

The issue is that, by outputting the response body after each request, I have discovered that the first get request is successfully made, but the post request fails as it gets redirected to the sign in page.

Things I have tried:

1) Commenting out the get request. This allows the post request to succeed (no longer redirecting to the sign in page).

2) Putting the two requests in separate "it" blocks with the stub defined in each block. Does not make a difference, first request works but the second one gets redirected.

I am very confused since the stub is clearly working when there is only one request, but fails for any subsequent requests. I've been trying to solve this issue for the whole day, and I am finally at a loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it fail if you do two `get` requests in the same block?

Comment: Yes, if I do two get requests the second one gets redirected. I outputted the current_user in the controller and it seems that the second request always results in a nil for current_user, which means the stubbing is not working as it should be... or am I not understanding how it works? I outputted the class name that current_user is being called on and it is the correct controller for both of the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally discovered the problem.

In test.rb, config.cache_classes was set to false (no idea why since it defaults to true).

You want config.cache_classes to be set to true in testing environments, otherwise classes will be reloaded on every request and its methods will override the stub.